# Rolling with slipping

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, rotational-kinematics

> A tundra buggy, which is a bus fitted with oversized wheels, is stuck in Churchill, Manitoba, on slippery ice. The wheel radius is 0.86 m. The speedometer goes from 0 to 27 km/h while the buggy moves a total distance of 8.0 m in 9.0 s. Find the magnitude of the tangential acceleration at the bottom of the wheel at the end of 7.0 s.

I am having trouble with this question especially because it is rolling with slipping.  I have a harder time grasping this concept compared to rolling without slipping.  My thought process so far is that wheel thinks it has gone farther than in reality of how far the truck has traveled. My problem is that I cannot relate the angular properties of the wheel to the truck moving. How is it even possible to find tangential acceleration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part in this question is the 'speedometer' part. The speedometer measures the speed of the car if its tyres had the same angular acceleration as in the slipping case, but driven on the road (on which the tyre doesn't slip).

It is obvious here, that $a_{com} \neq r\alpha$, where $a_{com}$ is the linear acceleration of the tyre's COM on the slippery ground, $r$ is the radius of the wheel, and $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration of the tyre.

So, there are two $a_{com}$s here. One is what the car feels it is or what the speedometer measures, and the other what it actually is. Let us say the two are $a_{com}'$ and $a_{com}$ respectively.

Now, since the speedometer measures $a_{com}'$, the final velocity of the car as per it is $27kmph=7.5\frac ms$ at the end of $9$ seconds. 
$$\therefore a_{com}'={7.5-0 \over 9}\frac {m}{s^2}=0.83\frac {m}{s^2}$$

Since the 'car' moves $8m$ in $9s$, it essentially means that the COM of the tyre has moved by the same amount.
$$\therefore a_{com}=\frac{2x}{t^2}=\frac{2 \times 8}{9^2} \frac{m}{s^2}= 0.19\frac{m}{s^2}$$

We know however, that $a_{com}' = r\alpha$. Since any point on the periphery of the tyre has a linear acceleration $r\alpha$ with respect to a frame where the COM is stationary, that acceleration is thus also equal to $a_{com}'$.

At a point on the bottom of the tyre, $a_{com}'$ (linear acceleration of any point on the periphery of the tyre with respect to a frame where the COM is stationary) and $a_{com}$ have opposite directions.

Thus the magnitude of the net linear (tangential) acceleration at the bottom of the wheel is $$|a_{com}'- a_{com}|= \boxed {0.64 \frac{m}{s^2}}(answer)$$

The time does not matter here since both accelerations are constants.

Note: While solving this problem, I have assumed that all accelerations are constant and that they have asked us to find the tangential acceleration of the bottom of the tyre 'with respect to a stationary frame'.

Comment: Hi Simha, why is the distance multiplied by 2 in the calculation for tangential acceleration for the reference of the car?

Comment: @tehricefarmer: We know that $x=\frac 12 a_{com}t^2$ (u=0 because the car starts fom rest). Thus, with a bit of rearrangment, we get that expression.